# In the UK, are young white men the most derided ethnic/gender/age group?

Tags: united-kingdom, racism, demographics

A month, or so, ago this [YouGov study](https://yougov.co.uk/news/2015/12/14/young-white-men-most-derided/) was trending on FB and attracting some controversy.

> **The most derided ethnic group in Britain: young white men**
> YouGov data from 48 separate surveys reveals that young white men are seen as the worst ethnic, gender or age group on five negative traits – and the second worst on five positive traits
>
> [...]
>
> The lousy reputation of young white men is one of the most striking things to emerge from our surveys. When we look at individual characteristics, white men in their 20s have the worst reputation, out of all 48 groups, for drunkenness, sleeping around, hard work and politeness. They also have the joint worst score, with young black Caribbean men, for a belief that they are prone to drug-taking.

From my understanding, the surveys asked a number of UK participants to rate an array of different human traits (young-old, black-white-asian-etc, man-woman, etc) by answering a series of questions about their likelihood to steal, drink, be polite, etc. The YouGov study claims to have found that young white men are the most derided (i.e. rated high for negative attributes).

Is this surprising result corroborated or undermined by other independent studies?

Comment: According to the [FAQ](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/faq#questions), Skeptics.SE is for researching the evidence behind the claims you hear or read. This question doesn't appear to have any doubtful claims to investigate. Please edit it to reference a notable claim and flag for moderator attention to re-open (or get 5 re-open votes).

Comment: @DanGetz Prejustice is a word meaning pre-judged. You can be Prejudiced, as you are full of pre-judgement against people. Or you cna be Prejudiced against, aka others hold judgemental views on you without even knowing you. I edited a little to make it more clear.

Comment: @Oddthinking Is not the article I link to making a notable public claim?

Comment: Another thing that it might be good to clarify is that the study claims that **young** white men are prejudiced against, and also that older white men are not.

Comment: The article also has a *very* prominent link to [a page for exploring the data](https://yougov.co.uk/news/2015/12/14/prejudice-data/), which gives a more nuanced view of what was actually being said by the survey participants.

Comment: @DanGetz I was not sure about that. Yes, the specific claim is for YWM, but the Young vs Old is not really a controversial claim in the same class. And since all OWM were YWM for a significant portion of their lives, so were still prejudiced against in general, if the claim is to be believed. I wanted to narrow the focus, and thought it was not being inaccurate. But maybe I was wrong?

Comment: @JonathonWisnoski the article and its data don't claim that old white men are not as prejudiced as young white men. It claims that old white men are "more praised" than other people in general. In the data, white men in their 40s scores better than men of many other races/origins in their 40s. Men in their 60s scored better than anyone else of any race, age, or gender, except for women in their 60s.

Comment: Also, the meaning of "White" in this study is not quite what one might imagine: it doesn't include Polish or Australians (or Jewish people for that matter). It seems to be intended to mean "white, native-born, and not Jewish"?

Comment: @DanGetz I don't believe that is supposed to be taken as an exclusive stats. I don't think the questions asked for example  were "what do you think of whites (excluding pols and Jews)". They asked some questions about white, others about Pols, and others about Jews. In that way "White" in the study is whatever the precipitants considered "White".

Comment: @JonathonWisnoski oh right, I forgot that the surveys were done separately.

Comment: Maybe ask on the [cognitive science site](http://cogsci.stackexchange.com). Show plenty of prior research, they're one of the fussier sites. There's quite a lot of American research, where they show faces then objectively measure things like response times to words to test for priming.

Comment: I made a major edit to match the specific claim that was edited in. The YouGov survey didn't talk about prejudice, so I removed mention of it as a distraction. It spoke about young white men, not all white men. The old title asking if there was a lot of research was not the claim made, so that was distracting too.

Comment: Do I understand it correctly, that you want to have more evidence of _people thinking_ they have those traits, and not of _them actually having_ these traits?